# Выход за границы диапазона

Tags: pascal

Код должен выполнять ф-ию прохода по дорогам.

т.е. первым числом задается число городов, а вторым кол-во дорог между ними
Нужно найти любую кольцевую дорогу по городам

Выдает ошибку выхода за границы диапазона 1..12

```
var i,n,k,j,count,count2,m:integer;
    a:array [1..12] of string;
    s,s1:string;

function rec(st:string; a:array[1..12] of string):string;
var x,cod,b:integer;
    x1,s1,istr:string;
begin
  for i:=1 to length(st) do

      begin
        str(i,istr);
        s1:=istr;
        writeln('a[b] = ',a[b]);
        writeln('s[i] = ',s[i]);

        for b:=1 to 12 do
        begin
        if pos(s[i],a[b])<>0 then
                    begin
                      s1:=s1+s[i];
                      rec(a[b],a);
                    end;
      end;

    end;
    writeln(s1);
end;

BEGIN
  readln(n,m);
   for count:=1 to m DO
    begin
      WHILE count2<>m DO
        begin
          readln(i,j);

          str(j,s);
          str(i,s1);
          a[i]:=a[i]+s;
          a[j]:=a[j]+s1;

          inc(count2);
        end;


    end;



    for i := 1 to 12 do begin
   writeln('a[', i, ']=',a[i]);
    end;
       write(rec(a[1],a));


END.
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [рекурсивная функция путешествия по 'дорогам'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1046783/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%bc)

Comment: @And, Там был вопрос по поводу реализации, а тут проблемы с кодом

Comment: @Tip  Если вы нашли ответ на тот вопрос, то отметьте существующий, либо добавьте свой.  Чтобы «гештальт закрылся».

Comment: А что вы вводите вот здесь: `readln(i,j);`?